# Why I am getting errors while installing firebase-tools using npm?

Tags: firebase, npm, npm-install, firebase-tools

I am installing firebase-tools using  `npm i firebase-tools`
**Errors are :
**

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or 
have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

I updated npm but still getting same erorrs. Also changed the proxy setting using

```
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Also changed timeout settings but nothing changed.

```
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000
```